# Create symmetrical matrix from list of values

Tags: python, performance, matrix, numpy

I need to make a matrix (in the form of a numpy array) by taking a list of
parameters of length N and returning an array of dimensions N+1 x N+1 where the off-diagonals are symmetric and each triangle is made up of the values given. The diagonals are equal to 0 - the row sum of the off-diagonals.

I don't really like having to instantiate an empty array, fill the top triangle, then create a new matrix with the bottom triangle filled in. I'm wondering if I can do this in fewer lines (while still being readable) and also wondering if it can be made faster. `vals` is never going to be very large (between 2 and 100, most likely) but the operation is going to be repeated many times.

```
def make_sym_matrix(dim, vals):

    my_matrix = np.zeros([dim,dim], dtype=np.double)

    my_matrix[np.triu_indices(dim, k=1)] = vals
    my_matrix = my_matrix + my_matrix.T
    my_matrix[np.diag_indices(dim)] = 0-np.sum(my_matrix, 0)

    return my_matrix
```

Comment: If you are doing this many times for the same `dim`, try to reuse `xy=np.triu_indices(dim,1)`.  For `dim=4`, that takes about half the time; so reuse may double the overall speed.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I would use `np.zeros()` to initialize your matrix. Using `np.empty()` can create a matrix with large values relative to your values on the diagonal which will affect the computation of `0-np.sum(my_matrix, 0)` due to numeric underflow.

For example, just run this loop and you'll see it happen:

```
for i in xrange(10):
  print make_sym_matrix(4, [1,2,3,4,5,6])
```

Secondly, you can avoid taking the transpose by re-using the triu indices.
Here is the code combining these two ideas:

```
def make_sym_matrix(n,vals):
  m = np.zeros([n,n], dtype=np.double)
  xs,ys = np.triu_indices(n,k=1)
  m[xs,ys] = vals
  m[ys,xs] = vals
  m[ np.diag_indices(n) ] = 0 - np.sum(m, 0)
  return m
```

Comment: Already switched from np.empty to np.zeros, thanks for the suggestions. This should be faster than the code I have, right? Because it doesn't involve creating another matrix (like I have in the line: `my_matrix = my_matrix + my_matrix.T`)

Comment: I would imagine so, but ultimately the only way to know for sure is to benchmark it.

Comment: `0 - np.sum(m, 0)` could be just `-np.sum(m, 0)`, and `m[ np.diag_indices(n) ] -= np.sum(m, 0)` seems faster still.

Comment: At least on this small sample array I'm not seeing much difference in time.  Timewise a transpose is a trivial operation.